# Infinite loop for SAML request in spring-saml

Tags: saml, spring-saml

I am seeing extremely wired and inconsistent behavior in webapp with spring-saml.

Our setup -

- Two IDP being chosen based on url pattern - implemented using CustomSAMLContextProviderImpl (works fine based on url it redirects to configured IDP)
- Configured both SAML provider/IDP using CachingMetadataManager with list of ExtendedMetadataDelegate. Based on [explaination here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/saml/127716-idp-initiated-saml-sign-on-with-multi-tenant-sp-configuration?p=610912#post610912) and [code-example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/sample/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml#L138)
- spring mvc application (version - 4.1.6.RELEASE)
- spring saml security (version - 1.0.1.RELEASE)

Now, sometime I observe infinite looping behavior between IDP(https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2) and SP (https://my-application.com/).

Attaching piece of log

```
    16:29:07.829 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG c.s.s.s.CustomSAMLContextProviderImpl - Using default SP/Local EntityId https://my-application.com/
16:29:07.829 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider - Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: https://my-application.com/
16:29:07.829 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of https://my-application.com/
16:29:07.829 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Metadata document did not contain a descriptor for entity https://my-application.com/
16:29:07.829 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Metadata document did not contain any role descriptors of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor for entity https://my-application.com/
16:29:07.830 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Metadata document does not contain a role of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor supporting protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol for entity https://my-application.com/
16:29:07.830 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider - Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: https://my-application.com/
16:29:07.830 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of https://my-application.com/
16:29:07.831 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver - Building credential from keystore entry for entityID sam, usage type UNSPECIFIED
16:29:07.831 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver - Processing PrivateKeyEntry from keystore
16:29:07.831 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.c.EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry - Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableEntityIDCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria
16:29:07.832 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver - Building credential from keystore entry for entityID sam, usage type UNSPECIFIED
16:29:07.832 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver - Processing PrivateKeyEntry from keystore
16:29:07.832 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.c.EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry - Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableEntityIDCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria
16:29:07.845 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool - Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing'
16:29:07.846 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool - Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion'
16:29:07.847 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool - Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl'
16:29:07.847 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG c.s.s.s.CustomSAMLContextProviderImpl - Using default IDP/Peer EntityId https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2
16:29:07.847 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider - Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2
16:29:07.847 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2
16:29:07.847 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil - Index for AssertionConsumerService not specified, returning default
16:29:07.847 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
16:29:07.847 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
16:29:07.847 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint - Processing SSO using WebSSO profile
16:29:07.847 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
16:29:07.848 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
16:29:07.848 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
16:29:07.848 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
16:29:07.848 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
16:29:07.848 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
16:29:07.848 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl - Using default consumer service with binding urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
16:29:07.848 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.w.m.encoder.BaseMessageEncoder - Beginning encode message to outbound transport of type: org.opensaml.ws.transport.http.HttpServletResponseAdapter
16:29:07.848 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.b.e.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder - Deflating and Base64 encoding SAML message
16:29:07.848 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.w.m.encoder.BaseMessageEncoder - Marshalling message
16:29:07.850 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.b.e.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder - Building URL to redirect client to
16:29:07.850 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.b.e.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder - Generating signature with key type 'RSA', algorithm URI 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1' over query string 'SAMLRequest=jVJLa8JAEL73V4S956n4WEzEVqSCxWBiD72tu6MuJLtxZxPaf9%2FEKLWX0tMwMN%2BD75vZ%2FLMsnAYMSq1iEnoBcUBxLaQ6xWSfr9wJmSdPM2RlEVV0Uduz2sGlBrTOAhGMbXEvWmFdgsnANJLDfreJydnaCqnvX5iHX%2BWJ1SfwGJ6jbuMVeFyXfkfqZ9mWOMuWTypmrybuUAGNK5V1S2G8CyvYATswUxZ4D0ftS1H52eJtExFnpQ2Hq8GYHFmBQJz1MiYsHB%2BOo0MwCIdSiDAYiLNgRyZ4xKftbI8wZYiygR8YYg1rhbbVikkUhCM3GLjhNA9HNJrSYOxNhpMP4qRGW8118SxVn1dtFNUMJVLFSkBqOe3M0cgL6KE%2FQvqa56mbbrOcOO%2F33KMu97YJhbRP%2Bm%2Bu6iZMkr4YenVsHhn%2BJmD36kjyj6Jm%2FqNKclt%2Ff0PyDQ%3D%3D&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1'
16:29:07.851 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.opensaml.xml.security.SigningUtil - Computing signature over input using private key of type RSA and JCA algorithm ID SHA1withRSA
16:29:07.860 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.opensaml.xml.security.SigningUtil - Computed signature: 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
16:29:07.860 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.b.e.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder - Generated digital signature value (base64-encoded) CrJd4zOolooPykAynVLR4P71Lsw665S/Wo6Va1YPY8pHvepk8WESgfKTIMWZdzTcYd163yuHpE0W8/Y50FIhsGkJZ5FomWU2Ypv6cmBr0G+VyL2Dzo3epL2hMVnkDPvlH53NN/VWzytGU2ehgFZ/Xp2VCStB9CRH7FfXfExm19BhXKzygANCLnUtp46hKydNK9ed81aGo07SnjoJyWfynBs6y+DHUjhLF9fmD1KB4H1pYd7b0neOqHLGwL4hHBVLzbZjwNFMiszbYQhOjVKs33bjSWJJqVJXFjKnIhRs2VFQWP6B+8gavB3nXuX+IoUZ9eXdJEFJfAGVgHlewcgVIA==
16:29:07.860 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG PROTOCOL_MESSAGE - 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://my-application.com//saml/SSO"
    Destination="https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2"
    ForceAuthn="false" ID="a17bf6b0314idd103dhdafadc2c9afa"
    IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2016-03-19T16:29:07.848Z"
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
    Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://my-application.com/</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>

16:29:07.860 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.w.m.encoder.BaseMessageEncoder - Successfully encoded message.
16:29:07.860 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.s.storage.HttpSessionStorage - Storing message a17bf6b0314idd103dhdafadc2c9afa to session 09CFF767DEC97C3B752DBD9E609B15DF
16:29:07.860 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] INFO  o.s.s.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger - AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;127.0.0.1;https://my-application.com/;https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2;;;
#BOOKMARK-REQUEST-ENDS
# EXPECTS = DEBUG o.s.s.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter - Attempting SAML2 authentication using profile urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:profiles:SSO:browser
#BOOKMARK-REQUEST-STARTS
16:30:50.203 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG c.s.s.s.CustomSAMLContextProviderImpl - Using default SP/Local EntityId https://my-application.com/
16:30:50.203 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider - Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: https://my-application.com/
16:30:50.203 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of https://my-application.com/
16:30:50.203 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Metadata document did not contain a descriptor for entity https://my-application.com/
16:30:50.203 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Metadata document did not contain any role descriptors of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor for entity https://my-application.com/
16:30:50.204 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Metadata document does not contain a role of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor supporting protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol for entity https://my-application.com/
16:30:50.204 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider - Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: https://my-application.com/
16:30:50.204 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of https://my-application.com/
16:30:50.205 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver - Building credential from keystore entry for entityID sam, usage type UNSPECIFIED
16:30:50.205 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver - Processing PrivateKeyEntry from keystore
16:30:50.205 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.c.EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry - Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableEntityIDCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria
16:30:50.205 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver - Building credential from keystore entry for entityID sam, usage type UNSPECIFIED
16:30:50.205 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver - Processing PrivateKeyEntry from keystore
16:30:50.205 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.c.EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry - Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableEntityIDCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria
16:30:50.219 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool - Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing'
16:30:50.219 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool - Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion'
16:30:50.220 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool - Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl'
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG c.s.s.s.CustomSAMLContextProviderImpl - Using default IDP/Peer EntityId https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider - Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil - Index for AssertionConsumerService not specified, returning default
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint - Processing SSO using WebSSO profile
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
16:30:50.221 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl - Using default consumer service with binding urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
16:30:50.222 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.w.m.encoder.BaseMessageEncoder - Beginning encode message to outbound transport of type: org.opensaml.ws.transport.http.HttpServletResponseAdapter
16:30:50.222 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.b.e.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder - Deflating and Base64 encoding SAML message
16:30:50.222 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.w.m.encoder.BaseMessageEncoder - Marshalling message
16:30:50.224 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.b.e.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder - Building URL to redirect client to
16:30:50.224 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.b.e.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder - Generating signature with key type 'RSA', algorithm URI 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1' over query string 'SAMLRequest=jVLJbsIwEL33KyLfs5myWSSIFqEiURWR0ENvxkwTS4kdPE7U%2Fn0TAiq9oB5Hepvem9n8qyycBgxKrSISegFxQAl9lCqLyD5duRMyjx9myMuCVmxR21zt4FQDWmeBCMa2vGetsC7BJGAaKWC%2F20Qkt7ZC5vsn7uF3mfE6A49jTrtLVOAJXfqdqJ8kb8RZtnpScXsOcaUeoXGlsm55NN6JF%2FyAHZkrC6Kno%2FblsfKTxeuGEmeljYBzwIh88gKBOOtlRLgYZmOZc3kYwUAOaC7HUownU55lj8MOg1uOKBv4ZSHWsFZoW6uI0CAcucHADadpOGKDgA0Dj9Lwgzhbo60WuniSqq%2BrNoppjhKZ4iUgs4J12Rj1AnboQche0nTrbt%2BSlDjv19ppV3s7hELWF31fq7oYk7jfhZ0Tm1uF%2BwL8uhyJ%2F7HTzL91iS%2Fn32eIfwA%3D&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1'
16:30:50.224 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.opensaml.xml.security.SigningUtil - Computing signature over input using private key of type RSA and JCA algorithm ID SHA1withRSA
16:30:50.232 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.opensaml.xml.security.SigningUtil - Computed signature: 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
16:30:50.232 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.b.e.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder - Generated digital signature value (base64-encoded) eQG+3Xm9JxNlYBBovoNZblkyqQLMNq9pP0fOn2OirJOHQDxxOVFnPscS+Mwi7+KhN3JhbzqC0cFO7nVH/QT5Nm6WPGLYrzH9U+tN7Zs6GGmo3wwKUrkBYhpex8n/XZKz56kY3lt/rWEAL/z4+jdmyPoq66nVEC24AHOAXZR/jRM0GXsijWKXadeZaKtEjTYJDkNi4rybYUkWHjrr/psuvwe3ZlTljKLwXtAqDjk5wmbASyWanRtMwfxPEkqMQ9ApyOXh3m9e2Jh2L0Ix3Bgv0YVeUxb80dE0ON6F0x83AHVwBsPG80NqZEutGsFJ7/3HXv/P7NE4IZsPcu862lSzBg==
16:30:50.233 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG PROTOCOL_MESSAGE - 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://my-application.com//saml/SSO"
    Destination="https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2"
    ForceAuthn="false" ID="ac5g7ihaib6e3i32hi7ic789agg45e"
    IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2016-03-19T16:30:50.221Z"
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
    Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://my-application.com/</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>

16:30:50.233 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.w.m.encoder.BaseMessageEncoder - Successfully encoded message.
16:30:50.233 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.s.storage.HttpSessionStorage - Storing message ac5g7ihaib6e3i32hi7ic789agg45e to session 5E6F51ACA1C337DFEA1BAE43F8C0B17D
16:30:50.233 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] INFO  o.s.s.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger - AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;127.0.0.1;https://my-application.com/;https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2;;;
#BOOKMARK-REQUEST-ENDS
# EXPECTS = DEBUG o.s.s.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter - Attempting SAML2 authentication using profile urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:profiles:SSO:browser
#REFRESH-METADATA-STARTS
16:31:06.138 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider - Beginning refresh of metadata from '/opt/CONFIG/APP/metadata/idp-meta-nsl.xml'
16:31:06.139 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider - resource /opt/CONFIG/APP/metadata/idp-meta-nsl.xml was last modified 2016-02-05T00:02:42.000Z
16:31:06.139 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider - Metadata from '/opt/CONFIG/APP/metadata/idp-meta-nsl.xml' has not changed since last refresh
16:31:06.139 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider - Computing new expiration time for cached metadata from '/opt/CONFIG/APP/metadata/idp-meta-nsl.xml
16:31:06.140 [Timer-0] INFO  o.o.s.m.p.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider - Next refresh cycle for metadata provider '/opt/CONFIG/APP/metadata/idp-meta-nsl.xml' will occur on '2016-03-19T16:36:06.140Z' ('2016-03-19T16:36:06.140Z' local time)
16:36:06.141 [Timer-0] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider - Beginning refresh of metadata from '/opt/CONFIG/APP/metadata/idp-meta-nsl.xml'
#BOOKMARK-REFRESH-METADATA-STARTS
#BOOKMARK-REQUEST-STARTS
16:59:09.514 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG c.s.s.s.CustomSAMLContextProviderImpl - Using default SP/Local EntityId https://my-application.com/
16:59:09.515 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider - Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: https://my-application.com/
16:59:09.516 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of https://my-application.com/
16:59:09.516 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Metadata document did not contain a descriptor for entity https://my-application.com/
16:59:09.516 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Metadata document did not contain any role descriptors of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor for entity https://my-application.com/
16:59:09.516 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Metadata document does not contain a role of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor supporting protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol for entity https://my-application.com/
16:59:09.516 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider - Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: https://my-application.com/
16:59:09.516 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of https://my-application.com/
16:59:09.517 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver - Building credential from keystore entry for entityID sam, usage type UNSPECIFIED
16:59:09.517 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver - Processing PrivateKeyEntry from keystore
16:59:09.517 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.c.EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry - Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableEntityIDCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria
16:59:09.517 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver - Building credential from keystore entry for entityID sam, usage type UNSPECIFIED
16:59:09.517 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver - Processing PrivateKeyEntry from keystore
16:59:09.517 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.x.s.c.c.EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry - Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableEntityIDCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria
16:59:09.531 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool - Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing'
16:59:09.532 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool - Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion'
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool - Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl'
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG c.s.s.s.CustomSAMLContextProviderImpl - Using default IDP/Peer EntityId https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider - Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider - Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.saml.util.SAMLUtil - Index for AssertionConsumerService not specified, returning default
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint - Processing SSO using WebSSO profile
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.m.support.SAML2MetadataHelper - Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
16:59:09.533 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl - Using default consumer service with binding urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
16:59:09.534 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.w.m.encoder.BaseMessageEncoder - Beginning encode message to outbound transport of type: org.opensaml.ws.transport.http.HttpServletResponseAdapter
16:59:09.534 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.b.e.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder - Deflating and Base64 encoding SAML message
16:59:09.534 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.w.m.encoder.BaseMessageEncoder - Marshalling message
16:59:09.536 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.b.e.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder - Building URL to redirect client to
16:59:09.536 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.b.e.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder - Generating signature with key type 'RSA', algorithm URI 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1' over query string 'SAMLRequest=jVLLasJAFN33K8Ls89SIGUzEVqSCRTFpF92Nk6sZSWbi3Im0f9%2FEKLUb6fLCeXHOnUy%2FqtI6g0ahZEx8xyMWSK5yIQ8xec8W9phMk6cJsqoMajprTCG3cGoAjTVDBG1a3ouS2FSgU9BnweF9u4pJYUyN1HVPzMHv6sCaAzgMi6C7eA0OV5XbibppuibWvNUTkplLiBs1h7MtpLGrXDsnVrIddmQmDfCejsoVee2ms7dVQKyF0hwuAWOyZyUCsZbzmLBgGIp9uIOhPx4ci9CPjsWQ7cZcHAd51GJwwxDFGX5ZiA0sJZrWKiaB549sb2D7UeaPaBhRL3LCwfCTWButjOKqfBayr6vRkiqGAqlkFSA1nHbZaOB4dNeDkL5m2cberNOMWB%2B32oOu9nYIibQv%2BrFWfTUmSb8LvSTW9wqPBdhtOZL8Y6eJe%2B%2BSXM%2B%2Fz5D8AA%3D%3D&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1'
16:59:09.536 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.opensaml.xml.security.SigningUtil - Computing signature over input using private key of type RSA and JCA algorithm ID SHA1withRSA
16:59:09.544 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.opensaml.xml.security.SigningUtil - Computed signature: 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
16:59:09.544 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.s.b.e.HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder - Generated digital signature value (base64-encoded) PzmHBagCqrbghOP6Ah+U53PmbYZPX6cSCL2WyjMSUl+Lv3+5FOayq2BsraY7SjhGKA/oM9JQx8RAUCZ8lL3lhcKD9b9odubP7SOBkf4qCwPHpvs0ZRFEoTK7e9hIWw7sRm+Et0j7bxChEynmZyeevRQcjkjfoShIY62S7WwPv37JJaYf4tMFoCiRPIdrTp2VWDcrrBN4k2LMIBBVfC2GPaE8y8wXzDItq4UwjdSVsx/QCK2kgTNh2ly31e4RHQ9Ffoo7DDe/JlPNu5mBK+8HNsaGtFS6v2mciDnVXWqEb9H578D3pWSVJqakIw9TNioKuaPKKEOTtLK4HA59ZojbTQ==
16:59:09.545 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG PROTOCOL_MESSAGE - 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://my-application.com//saml/SSO"
    Destination="https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2"
    ForceAuthn="false" ID="a245if5be4183jh519jh4ab8cij3d9"
    IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2016-03-19T16:59:09.534Z"
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
    Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://my-application.com/</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>

16:59:09.545 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.o.w.m.encoder.BaseMessageEncoder - Successfully encoded message.
16:59:09.545 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.s.storage.HttpSessionStorage - Storing message a245if5be4183jh519jh4ab8cij3d9 to session 0AFFA9527C8EEF8479BFCB6AE6655D3B
16:59:09.545 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] INFO  o.s.s.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger - AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;127.0.0.1;https://my-application.com/;https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2;;;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

As far as you obtained:

`16:59:09.545 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] INFO  o.s.s.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger - AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;127.0.0.1;https://my-application.com/;https://default-idp.com/sso/idp/SAML2`

the **AuthN** process on the IdP-side has been completed.

Generally, there are two main cases:

- there is an error in your implementation of `SAMLUserDetailsService` interface. In particular, check if the list of authorities for the instance of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` (returned by the method `loadUserBySAML`) contains at least one  `org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority`, properly configured according to your role model.
- there is an unexpected behavior while executing the filter chain, thus the **security context** is cleaned right after the authentication process (i.e., **[Spring Security on Wildfly / Undertow: error executing the filter chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559866/spring-security-on-wildfly-undertow-error-executing-the-filter-chain)**).

If your issue doesn't belong to those two cases, please provide a more verbose log to better point out the cause of the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you import trust of your IDP in SP machines, and alos make sure SP and IDP in same time , we faced a similar issue and an system restart of IDP and SP has solved the issue.